# Remove the "{}" from the json data generated using Newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.json to convert the c# object into json data. In that i have object as property and when serializing the object, the property which is of type object is parsed into "{}". Is there any way to remove that?? I tried DefaultValueAttribute but its not working.. Please give any suggestions.

Example

```
public class A
{
  public B b1{get;set;}

 }
```

When serailizing it will produce like this.

```
b1{}
```

Is there any way to remove it???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of object is B?

Comment: Do you want to parse it server side or client side?

Comment: are you sure it doesn't say `"b1":{}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `b1` property to null:

```
a.b1 = null;
```

and use the following setting to ignore null values:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
};
```